# How to get audio samples of music in iPod Library when it is being played?

Tags: ios, audio

I need to get the audio samples of the iPod music being played in real time.

The app EQu(http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/equ-the-quality-equalizer/id403704212?mt=8) has achieved this or it could not apply its filters, I think.

I've tried some methods but all in vain.

Is all I could do is to use the AVAssetReader and Writer to save a local converted file of the iPod music and play it back using low level techniques like AudioUnit? This local file could be very large I think.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several steps:

I. Create your local buffer, like below example, and you have to make sure
 
  a: there is enough empty space when you write to buffer
  b: there is enough data when you read from buffer
  by looking at the read/write idx

```
typedef struct
{
    //suppose non-interleaved LEI16 LPCM format
    SInt16 data[MUSIC_RING_BUFFER_NUM_CHANNEL][MUSIC_RING_BUFFER_SIZE];
    UInt16 readIdx;
    UInt16 writeIdx;
} MyRingBuffer;
```

II. Each time get some raw data from AVAssetTrackOuput, like

```
CMSampleBufferRef nextBuffer = [self.trackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
CMBlockBufferRef buffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer( nextBuffer );

size_t lengthAtOffset;
size_t totalLength;
char* data;

if( CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer( buffer, 0, &lengthAtOffset, &totalLength, &data ) != noErr )
{
    NSLog( @"error!" );
    return;
}

//raw audio sample data now in (char*) data
```

III. Then copy the data to your local buffer

The raw data for non-interleaved 16 bits LPCM will be like

```
    [2 bytes data x N, from left channel][2 bytes data x N from right channel]
```

use memcpy to copy to local buffer and update writeIdx

- Then write the **input render callback function** for EQ AudioUnit, it reads from your local buffer and update readIdx on another threads. And it calls to fill the buffer **on another thread** if there is enough space, like

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fillMusicBuffer:) withObject:Nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

BTW, always checking the audio format setting is the same or not. Get ASBD info from CMSampleBufferRef and compare to the AudioUnit input setting

```
const AudioStreamBasicDescription *audioDescription = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(nextBuffer));
```